# Why nameOnly doesn't have any effect on the return value

Tags: mongodb

According to this doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/, `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true} )` should return database name only exclude size block. But I tried with mongo-3.4.2 it dones't have any impact on the returned json object.

Comment: It works fine for me on 3.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nameOnly` option for the `listDatabases` command was added during the MongoDB 3.5 development cycle and backported to MongoDB 3.4.3 and 3.2.13 (see: [SERVER-3181](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3181) in the MongoDB issue tracker).

Since you are currently using a MongoDB 3.4.2 server, the `nameOnly` option will be ignored. If you want to use this option you will have to upgrade to a newer server version (eg. MongoDB 3.4.3 or later).

The MongoDB 3.4 documentation is currently missing a note on the version added; I've raised [DOCS-10213](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10213) in the MongoDB issue tracker to correct this oversight.

Comment: Thanks for doing this.

Comment: BTW, do you mean the mongo instance version of mongo shell version?

Comment: Support for the new command option requires a MongoDB 3.4.3 server. The `db.adminCommand()` helper in the shell passes the options through directly to the server command, so an older shell 3.4 shell version should still be fine in this case.